# fatal: Authentication failed "https://...." on ubuntu

Tags: git

I'm not able to push or pull any changes and I keep getting this error when ever I try to
`git push origin username`, I have tried the other commands like
`git config --system --unset credential.helper` didn't work.

OS: `Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS x86_64`

anybody here can help me out on this?

error

```
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://[company-name].git.beanstalkapp.com/ck5.git/'
```

when I try to log in that URL above it says `Not found` and it's the same URL on beanstalk for the repo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I found out what was the issue.

[Source](https://newbedev.com/git-push-missing-or-invalid-credentials-fatal-authentication-failed-for-https-github-com-username-repo-git)
Issue is with VS Code terminal not working sometimes.

As detailed in "git push origin master Missing or invalid credentials", and here:

> ```
> If you work with the JSON-settings file, insert the following line into it:
>   git.terminalAuthentication: false,
> ```

this fixed my issue of `git pull and push commits`